# AlpineJS, Laravel - change variable in data without event

Tags: javascript, laravel, alpine.js

```
I have following code:

<ul
    x-cloak
    x-show="activeDropdown === '{{$key}}'"
    x-collapse
    class="sub-menu text-gray-500">

    @loop($value as $itemKey => $itemValue)
        <li>
            <a
                @if(request()->route()->getName() === $itemValue['tableRoute'])
                    class="active"
                    x-data="{ activeDropdown : '{{$key}}' }"
                @endif
                id="{{$key}}_{{$itemKey}}"
                href="{{route($itemValue['tableRoute'])}}">
                {{ $itemValue['label']  }}
            </a>
        </li>
    @endloop

</ul>
```

And **AlpineJS** code:

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener("alpine:init", () => {
        Alpine.data("sidebar", () => ({
            activeDropdown : null,
        }));
    });
</script>
```

The issue is that **activeDropdown** is not changed, and **ul** is hidden. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

With `x-data` you create a child component with a new `activeDropdown` variable that the parent component cannot access directly. Instead of that you should use [`x-init` directive](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/init) to set the active dropdown element:

```
            @if(request()->route()->getName() === $itemValue['tableRoute'])
                class="active"
                x-init="activeDropdown = '{{$key}}'"
            @endif
```

It will set the value of `activeDropdown` when the component is initialized.